# Como desabilitar nav-tabs bootstrap com php

Tags: php, html, css

Estou tentando desabilitar algumas `nav-tabs` que tenho com uma ação em `php`, mas estou tendo dificuldade em executar essa ação por completo, até consegui desabilitar as `nav-tabs` com esse código `class='disabled'` ao posicionar o mouse sobre as duas primeiras `tabs` o ícone de desabilitado aparece, mas se clico na mesma ela me mostra o conteúdo.
Estou fazendo um `select` para buscar algumas fases obrigatórias que o contrato deve possuir, se o resultado for maior que zero as duas primeiras abas devem estar habilitadas e mostrar os `forms` que nelas existem, do contrário, se o valor for zero as duas primeiras `tabs`precisam ficar desabilitadas pois o contrato só poderá ser preenchido se as Fases Obrigatórias estiverem cadastradas.

O que tenho é isso:

```
<div class="tabbable well" id="tabs-648642">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li <?php if ( $totalRows_FaseObrigatoriaTab > 0 ) { echo "class='enable'"; } else { echo "class='disabled'"; } ?> > <a href="#panel-1" data-toggle="tab">Fases</a> </li>
    <li <?php if ( $totalRows_FaseObrigatoriaTab > 0 ) { echo "class='enable'"; } else { echo "class='disabled'"; } ?> > <a href="#panel-2" data-toggle="tab">Doctos</a> </li>
<li> <a href="#panel-3" data-toggle="tab">Fases Obrigatórias</a> </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content"> 

    <div class="tab-pane active" id="panel-1"></div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="panel-2"></div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="panel-3"></div>

</div>

</div>
```

Estou suprimindo os códigos das `nav-tabs` para facilitar a visualização.

Comment: Não use o StackSnippet sem necessidade, ele é obviamente usado para reproduzir códigos html,css,js e no seu código existe php, o que é claro que não vai funcionar. LEIA: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ - Por favor entenda como uma critica construtiva ;)

Comment: Olá @Guilherme Nascimento, agradeço a dica, sem problema algum, foi marcada minha mesmo.